# Protractor verify password is hidden

Tags: node.js, testing, passwords, protractor, hidden-field

I'd like to using protractor script to verify given password is hidden not in clear text. However

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```

returns the clear text.

My questions:

- Is it possible to verify the hidden password with help of a protractor script?
- If yes, what is the correct function or what are the correct
  functions?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between a normal text field and password field is their type attribute. For normal text field, the value of `type` attribute is `<input type='text'>` and for password field `<input type='password'>`. So using protractor it can be verified using below code.

```
var passwordField = element(by.name("pass")); 
expect(passwordField.getAttribute("type")).toEqual("password");
```